# Manipulate dom with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I want to convert DOM mean the following list to a dropdown list of  menu. in DOM through AngularJS

```
<div class="maincontent">
        <my-directive></my-directive>
        <ul>
          <li>Option 1</li>
          <li>Option 2</li>
          <li>Option 3</li>
          <li>Option 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**directive**

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", [])
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    //....
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a directive element would work in this case as you would want something to trigger the dropdown(as a button click).

Here's what I did:

```
app.directive('dropdown', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

            elem.bind('click', function() {
                elem.toggleClass('dropdown-active');
                elem.addClass('active-recent');
            });

            $document.bind('click', function() {
                if(!elem.hasClass('active-recent')) {
                    elem.removeClass('dropdown-active');
                }
                elem.removeClass('active-recent');
            });

        }
    }
});
```

I made it with class attribute and here's the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/IipeWJtDWGuBAxtWAadV?p=preview